# maven command with -P dev option?

Tags: maven

i am beginner in maven. I know what `mvn clean install` does but recently soptted it with dev option.Here it is

```
mvn clean install -P dev
```

I am not sure what `-P dev` means here?

Comment: I'm sorry, but be being a beginner does not prevent you to read the official documentation, nor to perform a simple google search.

Comment: @gizmo i tries to go thru mvn -help option and google but did not get anything about dev option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the -P parameter activates profiles: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

you can execute `mvn help:active-profiles` to see which are active.

Comment: what does dev option do ?

Comment: dev is the id of the profile. if you search the pom.xml files there will be a profile with <id>dev</id> somewhere.